# How to assign camera source by its USB identity?

Tags: usb

USB cameras are automatically mounted to ubuntu. I have a case where i have multiple USB cameras in use. I'm mounting each camera on a different port on the laptop.

Sometimes during boot, camera 1 will be disconnected,  but camera 2 will be connected, and camera 2 will be assigned to `/dev/video1`, however the rest of my software assumes`/dev/video1` is linked to the camera 1.

What i would like is for if camera 1 is disconnected, then camera 2 will mount itself to its right location -  `/dev/video2` - and I can keep working.

Since these are USB devices i know they have a unique id. But i dont know anything about mounting video points enough to make this work.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I just needed to run `ls /dev/v4l/by-path/` The camera's USB port is consistently updated there, you can check by switching the camera on and off and watching its path value change there.

Alternatively, you can run `ls /dev/v4l/by-id/`, but this didn't work for me because all my cameras had the same ID. Specifying by USB port seems to work better for my situation.