# MIImageView & cheese apps can not find my Venus USB-2 camera

Tags: usb, camera, cheese

Please can you help.  I'm trying to move from Windows 10 to Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS 20.04 focal. The microscope camera is an essential tool in my research.

This is a re-post of a deleted post which was deservedly flamed for a lack of clarity & formatting. I apologise. This post is clear & nicely formatted but may contain redundant information and too many words.

The camera works & is recognised by guvcview.  Cheese and MIImageView do not find the camera when I have root permission. Nothing is mounted in `/media` when the camera is attached.

Could the problem be that cheese and MIImageView expect `<something>` to be mounted on `<some-path>`? The  camera generates a UUID but I can not mount from it.  Surely there should be some clean way of generating a mount point (if that **is** the solution) for legacy software!

Would the path reported by the `udevadm` command below vary depending on what other USB devices were mounted, where, and in what order etc?  https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2071236  implies that it does vary.

> ...used "some udev rules. [He] made a new file in /etc/udev/rules.d/ and called it "15-addison.rules".
> The rules ... are of the form:
> `SUBSYSTEM=="video4linux", ATTRS{serial}=="A52EE700", SYMLINK+="camright"`
> `SUBSYSTEM=="video4linux", ATTRS{serial}=="E966A1E0", SYMLINK+="camtleft"`
> `SUBSYSTEM=="video4linux", ATTRS{serial}=="6903B710", SYMLINK+="cambleft"`
> `SUBSYSTEM=="video4linux", ATTRS{serial}=="520EE700", SYMLINK+="camsec1"`
> `SUBSYSTEM=="video4linux", ATTRS{serial}=="111EE700", SYMLINK+="camsec2"`

If `mount` could use a UUID  [How to assign camera source by its USB identity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1176719/how-to-assign-camera-source-by-its-usb-identity) did not get an answer about this. I ran `lsusb` and used the `UUID` it generated in a mount command: `sudo mount -U 0ac8:3420 /media` and got this error message.

> `mount: /media: can't find UUID="0ac8:3420".`

If I can't `mount` from a UUID then I can't `automount` from a UUID.  Is `mount` broken?

That's enough words; I'm going back to my [too much information] research.

> What!?  Are you a microbiologist?  A gastroenterologist?  If you **still** really want to know then please read my profile.

`lsusb` edited output

> `Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0ac8:3420 Z-Star Microelectronics Corp. Venus USB2.0 Camera`

`v4l2-ctl --list-devices`

> `USB CAMERA  (usb-0000:00:14.0-3.4):`
>     `/dev/video0`
>     `/dev/video1`

4 relevant lines from `dmesg`

> `[    3.192523] kernel: usb 1-3.4: New USB device found, idVendor=0ac8, idProduct=3420, bcdDevice= 0.10`
> `[    3.192539] kernel: usb 1-3.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0`
> `[    3.192547] kernel: usb 1-3.4: Product: USB CAMERA`
> `[    3.192552] kernel: usb 1-3.4: Manufacturer: 4H1TEK`

4 new drivers appear in `/dev` when camera is plugged in

> 52a53
> > media0
> 185a187
> > v4l
> 214a217,218
> > video0
> > video1

`udevadm info --attribute-walk --name=/dev/media0` edited output

> looking at device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3/1-3.4/1-3.4:1.0/media0':
>     KERNEL=="media0"
>     SUBSYSTEM=="media"
>     DRIVER==""
>     ATTR{model}=="USB CAMERA "0"`

`udevadm info --attribute-walk --name=/dev/v4l` edited output

> Unknown device "/dev/v4l": Inappropriate ioctl for device

`udevadm info --attribute-walk --name=/dev/video0`  edited output

> looking at device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3/1-3.4/1-3.4:1.0/video4linux/video0':
>     KERNEL=="video0"
>     SUBSYSTEM=="video4linux"
>     DRIVER==""
>     ATTR{index}=="0"
>     ATTR{name}=="USB CAMERA "
>     ATTR{dev_debug}=="0"

`udevadm info --attribute-walk --name=/dev/video1`  edited output

> looking at device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3/1-3.4/1-3.4:1.0/video4linux/video1':
>     KERNEL=="video1"
>     SUBSYSTEM=="video4linux"
>     DRIVER==""
>     ATTR{index}=="1"
>     ATTR{dev_debug}=="0"
>     ATTR{name}=="USB CAMERA "